# Concat an ellipsis on end of Model after substring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is probably something so easy, but I am having a hard time finding the right syntax.  Basically I am using substring to cut a line short then I just want to add a "..." on the end.  I just cant seem to find the right way to do it.

```
@if (@Model.Name.Length > 20)
{
    @Model.Name.Substring(0, 20) //"..." goes here
}
else
{
    @Model.Name
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@string.Concat(Model.Name.Substring(0,20), "...")
```

Or even:

```
@(Model.Name.Substring(0, 20) + "...")
```

Comment: Both worked equally as well, thank you, couldn't quite get the right syntax.